# Must use "struct" tag to refer to type "label"

Tags: objective-c

I got an error Must use 'struct' tag to refer to type 'label'
What is not correct?? I marked by comments where error appears. My Xcode version is 5.0.2
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
.m

```
  #import "GameViewController.h"

@interface GameViewController ()

@end

@implementation GameViewController

-(void)generate{
    int a=1+arc4random() % 9;
    int b=1+arc4random() % 9;

    int sum=a+b;
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d + %d = ", a, b]; //here is error
    label.tag=sum;  //and here

}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self generate];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender {
    int num=[_answer.text intValue];
    UIAlertView *alert;
    if(num == _label.tag){
        alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Correct" message:@"Let's try another one!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        alert.tag =1;
    }else{
        alert =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Wrong!" message:@"That answer is incorrect" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Try again" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    }
    [alert show];
}

@end
```

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GameViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *answer;

- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender;
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `self.label.text` or `_label.text`

Comment: Thank you, it worked, but I did't understand, label and _label are just different variables? How it worked?))

Comment: I'm not sure what `label` would be and why you're getting that error.  Normally, the error you would see is that this variable is undefined, and it'd also recommend to you one of the two that I recommended.